# Exception while trying to insert entities using EF4.3.1

Tags: c#, database, exception, entity-framework-4

I've seen some posts here that look like mine, however I couldn't find the answer to my specific problem.

The thing is that I'm trying to insert an entity into the DB using a nav. prop.
however I'm constantly getting: `The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.`

```
using (EntitiesDatabase context = new EntitiesDatabase())
{
    if (UserHandler.Instance.User is Admin)
    {
        ((Admin)UserHandler.Instance.User).ProjectManagers.Add(
            new ProjectManager(firstNameTextBox.Text, lastNameTextBox.Text, usernameTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text));
    }
    else if (UserHandler.Instance.User is ProjectManager)
    {
        ((ProjectManager)UserHandler.Instance.User).Developers.Add(
            new Developer(firstNameTextBox.Text, lastNameTextBox.Text, usernameTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text));
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The error exception is thrown at line 5-6 of the code `(u.ProjectManagers.Add(new ProjectManager(...))`

**For clarity:**
`UserHandler` is a singelton that holds the reference to the logged on user.
The user has a navigation property

```
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectManager> ProjectManagers { get; set; }
```

That should actually insert the new project manager to the DB after I do `SaveChanges()` on the context.

I've done some simple tests on smaller projects (like the ones in the PluralSight tutorials) and it did work... for some reason these same lines do not work.
It really seems as if the new project manager I'm creating is being disposed before I try to insert it to the nav. prop. because I'm never getting to the save changes line...

From other answers I've seen, I guessed that the `using` statement for some reason disposes of things before it has reached the end bracket. I don't get why...
Could someone point me in the right way?

BTW this is not homework guys, it's a project of mine in which I am trying to learn C#, EF and other technologies.

Comment: on which line you getting error?

Comment: forgot to specify. im getting it in the line where i try to add things to the db... u.ProjectManagers.Add(new ProjectManager(...)) 6th line in the code

Comment: I think you need to work with current context, not with some kind user handler instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the context you get the `User` instance from are fetched in a different context, which are disposed.

You have two options either use the same context, or attach the entity to the new context using [ObjectContext.Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx) like this:

```
using (EntitiesDatabase context = new EntitiesDatabase())
{
  context.Attach(UserHandler.Instance.User);
  if (UserHandler.Instance.User is Admin)
  {
    ((Admin)UserHandler.Instance.User).ProjectManagers.Add(
       new ProjectManager(firstNameTextBox.Text, lastNameTextBox.Text, usernameTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text));
  }
  else if (UserHandler.Instance.User is ProjectManager)
  {
    ((ProjectManager)UserHandler.Instance.User).Developers.Add(
        new Developer(firstNameTextBox.Text, lastNameTextBox.Text, usernameTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text));
  }

  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I am using the same context, i'm just not adding the new entity to the dbset, im adding it into the ICollection I have in Admin and then doing context.SaveChanges()

Comment: But if `Admin` isn't attached to the current context, but fetched using a different context which has been disposed. You'll get this error. This means that attaching the `Admin` object to the context should fix the problem.

Comment: Admin was not tracked by this context so I had to attach it! thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the data context related to `UserHandler.Instance.User` isn't alive in the current calling context, and `UserHandler.Instance.User` isn't attached to the `context` more recently instantiated.

Comment: UserHandler is a singelton...it exists in all contexts i think :)